# How do I save updated nodes in getorgchart?

Tags: getorgchart

How do I get any updates made to nodes to save back to the server? I've looked at the server-edit demo on http://www.getorgchart.com/Demos/Server-Edit , but I can't get the POST event to work.

I'm using chrome web server for testing so maybe it's an issue with that? If I set up my readURL to be http://127.0.0.1/getorgchart/staff?callback=? then the data is retrieved but nothing renders.

If I just do http://127.0.0.1/getorgchart/staff? it all renders, but then when I set my updateURL to http://127.0.0.1/getorgchart/staff any updates get a 404 error stating "Unhandled request. Did you select a folder to serve?".

I'd really appreciate any tips and/or resources that would help me solve this problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following GitHub project as starting point

https://github.com/GetOrgChart/ASP.NET-MVC?files=1